# Nova página em html

Tags: html, css

Vamos supor que tenho um site chamado site.com.br, e dois arquivos HTML. Um chamado index.html, e outro, sub.html. Gostaria de fazer com que, o arquivo index.html fique no site como apenas site.com.br e o sub.html fique como `site.com.br/sub.html`.

Como posso fazer isso? Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Ele já ficará assim por padrão. Servidores, por padrão, buscarão um arquivo chamado `index` no diretório raiz quando nenhum arquivo é passado pela URL e quando passado, o servidor tentará abrir o arquivo. Você teve algum problema quando tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Tu está tentando fazer url amigável?
Se sim, apesar de não ser o melhor, usa pastas. O nome da pasta é o que vai ficar na URL e em cada pasta um arquivo index.html

Exemplo:
site.com/ [index.html]
site.com/pagina1/ [index.html (com outro conteúdo)]
site.com/pagina2/ [index.html (com outro conteúdo)]
site.com/pagina3/ [index.html (com outro conteúdo)]

Comment: O padrão do site é esse: Index.html os demais arquivos serão: URL/página.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel,

Por padrão, todo servidor identificará o arquivo `index.html` e o referenciará como uma "home" ou página inicial automaticamente e toda e qualquer outra página viria au final do endereço, como `/sub.html`. É possível configurar mais detalhes e poderia te dar exemplo, mas para isso precisaria de mais informações sobre qual servidor você estaria usando. Fico aguardando maiores informações para te auxiliar melhor!

Comment: Estou utilizando o GitHub Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Vou presumir que o site já se encontra num servidor web (pode ser com localhost). 
Caso o servidor for *Apache* é muito fácil resolver isso. Basta criar ou modificar o ficheiro/arquivo **.htaccess** na raiz do site (onde se encontra o index.html) com o seguinte código:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$1 [L]
```

Caso não funcione recomendo mudar o **index.html** para **index.php** e assim usar o seguinte código no **.htaccess**:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Atenção que para isto funcionar é necessário que o ***rewrite*** deve estar habilitado no servidor (por *default* está).
Também pode acontecer não estar a usar *Apache* e aí já está fora da minha área de conhecimento.
Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Mas desta forma, para qualquer URL acessada, será exibido o arquivo `index.html` e não foi isso o pedido. Talvez eu tenha entendido errado o que o autor quis dizer, mas normalmente não seria preciso fazer nada para obter o resultado que ele deseja, vide meu comentário na pergunta.

Comment: Cara, não precisa de tudo isso não. Basta colocar o index.html e o sub.html na raiz do servidor.